# Do I need to update the ESTA?

Tags: visas, esta

I have an ESTA, but it was from last time when we were in transit. This time we are staying in Hawaii. Do I need to update the ESTA?

Comment: Welcome to the site Richard. Please give us some more information so we can help, when was the last time you were in the US? Did your passport expire since then?

Comment: @blackbird Basically, you're asking for the question to be edited to make it so specific that the answer is literally either "yes" or "no" and the answer probably won't apply to anyone else. It seems better to just treat the question as "Under what circumstances does an ESTA need to be updated?" and answer it in its generality.

Comment: @DavidRicherby good point, that’d make for a better answer